# how to add an option or argument to default php artisan down command in laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-artisan

I want to add a `{--time=12}` to the `php artisan down` command in laravel that indicates the Expiration time of the `laravel-maintenance` cookie. also the `{--time}` could not be zero or negative.
Can anyone tell me how i can modify `php artisan down` command with these conditions?

Comment: Create your own artisan command with the desired functionality

Comment: @brombeer Can I name my new command as down? will it override the default down command?

Comment: No clue, probably not, that command already exists.